# Custom trailer in ISO message

Tags: jmeter, iso, jpos

I'm using Base24 channel in my jpos and I want to add extra characters after my trailer can anyone share your thought how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation, this implementation won't check that the received trailer matches the custom trailer, but you can add that code if needed.

```java
public class MyCustomBase24 extends Base24Channel {
  byte[] customTrailer = ...;
  protected sendMessageTrailer() {
    super.sendMessageTrailer();
    serverOut.write(customTrailer); //
  }
  protected byte[] streamReceive() {
    byte[] d = super.streamReceive();
    //read the extra trailer chars
    byte[] extra = new byte[customTrailer.length]; 
    serverIn.readFully(extra);
    return d;

  }
}
```

This class calls the `Base24Channel`'s `sendMessageTrailer` to send the `0x03` and then it sends the extra bytes, at receive time, after `Base24Channel` stopped receiving after the `0x03` it reads the extra bytes.

I'm assuming those extra bytes are present in incoming messages also, if not you wouldn't need to override the `streamReceive` method.

Then you just need to replace the `class` attribute of the XML deploy descriptor, with your custom class, instead of `org.jpos.iso.channel.Base24Channel`.